# How to dynamically add code to content script based on IP

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, ip

I wrote a pretty extensive chrome extension for mafia wars on facebook. The problem is that i gave it to a few people, who gave it to others. What I want is to add my friends ips to my server's database, which i can do. but when i give out the extension, i want as little code in it as possible, for obvious reasons. I have found no way to dynamically add more code to a content script though.

what i cant do:
keep my code on my server as a js file and only allow access to file based on ip, dynamically add the code to the chrome extension

Comment: Where this dynamic code is going to come from?

Comment: What obvious reasons are there to have as little as code possible in it?

Comment: so that if someone gives it out, they dont have the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject content script on demand using [`chrome.tabs.executeScript()`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/tabs.html#method-executeScript). The rest of your plan sounds good.

Comment: looking into executescript and this seems to be the answer. thank you